# when I trying to execute alter command using snowflake stored procedure giving error's?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have created stored procedure using below code I am getting error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc()
returns string not null
language javascript
as
$$
var sql_textA = "ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC'" ; 
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_textA}); 
var rs = stmt.execute();
var sql_textb="SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;"
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_textA}); 
var rs = stmt.execute();

return "succes";
$$
;

call testproc()
```

getting error like below
"Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'ALTER_SESSION'. At Statement.execute, line 4 position"

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the procedure with CALLER rights:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc()
returns string not null
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
var sql_textA = "ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC'" ; 
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_textA}); 
var rs = stmt.execute();
var sql_textb="SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;"
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_textb}); 
var rs = stmt.execute();

rs.next();

return rs.getColumnValue(1);
$$
;

call testproc();
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html#choosing-between-owner-s-rights-and-caller-s-rights

Comment: thanks for quick reply .can you please help me return current time stamp value using above procedure

Comment: how to see output value

Comment: I think you need to output the result of rs, instead of `success`

Comment: Sai, I have updated the procedure. Now it will fetch and return first row of the second query.